# How to install a yarn workspace package in sibling for use in a parent app

Tags: yarnpkg, yarn-workspaces

I have a yarn workspace with standalone, sibling packages

```
- Yarn Workspace
  - Data Package
  - UI Package
```

The `UI Package` depends on the `Data Package` and both packages need to be installed in a parent app:

```
- App
  - Data Package
  - UI Package
    - Data Package
```

I can't seem to pack the UI with its own copy of Data -- when adding UI to the app I get an error that the dependency cannot be found / the data package wasn't included.

---

```
// doesn't work: packages/ui-package/index.ts
import { DataService } from "../../data-package";
import { DataService } from "@scope/data-package";
```

```
// doesn't work: packages/ui-package/package.json
"@scope/data-package": "./data-package.tgz",
"@scope/data-package": "workspace:packages/data-package",
```

I feel that an option may be to copy the data tgz to the `dist` folder before packing (though after the `prepack` command which wipes the `dist` folder), but this seems like a hack, and that there's probably a simple yarn config to pack correctly. I feel that possibly  a root tsconfig could potentially handle this, but again these packages should be mostly independent, and adding build processes for something simple makes no sense.

---

Hopefully the problem makes sense, I'm curious how I can install Data into UI, bundle that, and include it alongside the Data package in a parent app.

Answer (score 1):

### Hack Solution

The hack solution I found was to install via the workspace command, then manually change the `package.json` entry to an absolute path (may be a different path on destination server):

1. **add via local workspace**: `yarn workspace @scope/ui-package add @scope/data-package`
2. **change package.json to absolute path**: `"@scope/data-package": "/absolute/path/to/data-package.tgz"`
3. **pack tgz**: `yarn workspace @scope/ui-package pack --filename ui-package.tgz`
4. **copy to app directory**, **`yarn remove @scope/ui-package`**, **delete cached files** (see below; two cached 'dependencies' install via this method), **`yarn add ./ui-package.tgz`**

---

### Using Yalc

I've seen a lot of people using `yalc` for package management, specifically **due to caching issues around `tgz` files** eg

- dependencies: `rm ~/.yarn/berry/cache/@scope-ui-package__PRESS_TAB_HERE__`
- resolutions: `rm .yarn/cache/@scope-ui-package__PRESS_TAB_HERE__`

`yalc` will apparently 'publish' a package to a global folder, and install as if it were through artifactory or some npm hub

I have not used `yalc` yet, but plan to

Comment: follow up, I remember yalc worked way better, highly recommend anyone having this problem to look into it